# Firebase action.payload returns id, but data is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

In my Firebase Cloud Firestore, I have a collection of galleries, and each gallery document has a subcollection of images.

[screnshoot Cloud Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a506N.png)
[screnshoot Cloud Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fT7E.png)
I was able to retrieve and display the galleries and the images inside each gallery, but when I try to retrieve the single image document, I get only the ID and the data is undefined (so it's like the name and the url of the image don't exist)

Here my image.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Image } from '../models/Image';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ImageService {
  images: Observable<Image[]>;
  image: Observable<any>;
  imageCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Image>;
  imageDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Image>;
  url!: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
  ) {}

  getGalleryImages(id: string | any): Observable<Image[]> {
    this.imageCollection = this.afs.collection(`galleries/${id}/images`);

    this.images = this.imageCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((changes) => {
        return changes.map((action) => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Image;
          console.log(data);
          const id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );

    return this.images;
  }

  getImageDetail(id: string | any) {
    this.imageDoc = this.afs.doc(`/images/${id}`);

    this.image = this.imageDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((action) => {
        const data = action.payload.data();

        const id = action.payload.id;
        console.log(data, id);
        return { id, ...data };
      })
    );

    return this.image;
    
  }
}
```

Here my image-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ImageService } from '../../../services/image.service';
import { Image } from '../../../models/Image';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-detail',
  templateUrl: './image-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-detail.component.css'],
})
export class ImageDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  image: Image | any;
  id: string;
  name: string | any;
  url: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private imageService: ImageService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getImage();
  }

  getImage() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.imageService.getImageDetail(id).subscribe((image) => {
      this.image = image;
      console.log(image);
      return image;
    });
  }

  
}
```

I even tried this but the result is the same

```
getImageDetail(id: string | any): Observable<Image[]> {
    this.imageDoc = this.afs.doc(`/images/${id}`);

    this.image = this.imageDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((action) => {
        const data = action.payload.data() as Image

        const id = action.payload.id;
        console.log(data, id);
        return { id, ...data };
      })
    );

    return this.image;
    
  }
```

Someone is able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: By doing ```this.imageDoc = this.afs.doc(`/images/${id}`);``` you incorrectly declare the doc: you need to use its full path, including the parent path.

Comment: Yes, I tried also with the full path
this.imageDoc = this.afs.doc(`galleries/${id}/images/${id}`) , but I still get data as undefined

Comment: The two ids must be different: the first one should be the id of the gallery doc and the second one should be the id of the image doc. ```this.imageDoc = this.afs.doc(`/galleries/${galleryId}/images/${id}`);```

Comment: Right! It does make a lot of sense! But sorry for the further question (it's my very first project angular/firebase), how I do declare the galleryId, with the path? 

`const galleryId = this.afs.doc(`galleries/${id}`);`

Answer (score 0):

The two ids must be different:

-the first one should be the id of the gallery doc and

-the second one should be the id of the image doc.

`` this.imageDoc = this.afs.doc(`/galleries/${galleryId}/images/${id}`); ``